# swi prolog standalone executable for mac not working as expected

Tags: macos, compilation, prolog

I am trying to create a prolog stand alone executable following the minimalistic example shown at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/UnixExe.html.

Everything seems to work fine, however if I try to execute on a different mac that does not have swi-prolog installed I get the following error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/lib/x86_64-darwin15.6.0/libswipl.dylib`

The command I run and its output:

```
pl_test|⇒ swipl --goal=hello --stand_alone=true -o hello -c hello.pl


% autoloading prolog_codewalk:must_be/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/error
% autoloading qsave:current_foreign_library/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/shlib
% autoloading error:assertion/1 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/debug
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:portray_clause/1 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/listing
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:clause_info/4 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/prolog_clause
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:initialization_layout/4 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/prolog_clause
% autoloading prolog_source:directory_file_path/3 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/filesex
% autoloading files_ex:use_foreign_library/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/shlib
% autoloading record:member/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/lists
% autoloading files_ex:maplist/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/apply
% autoloading files_ex:permission_error/3 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/error
% autoloading oset:reverse/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/lists
% autoloading prolog_debug:backtrace/1 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/prolog_stack
% autoloading prolog_codewalk:clause_name/2 from /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.2.3_2/libexec/lib/swipl-7.2.3/library/prolog_clause
% Autoloader: iteration 1 resolved 11 predicates and loaded 14 files in 0.101 seconds.  Restarting ...
% Autoloader: loaded 11 files in 2 iterations in 0.143 seconds
```

hello.pl is identical with the example provided on the website (see link above)

So the question is what am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if this applies to MacOS, but on Linux trying to make a "stand-alone" is too much trouble to be worth the effort. I hope that someone gives you a useful answer.

Comment: I switched to GNU prolog... the compilation worked like a charm out of the box. However I would not mind getting an answer for this one :)

Comment: The strength of SWI-Prolog are the extensive standard libraries. If you want "compiled" binaries, GNU-Prolog is definitely a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is on the page you've given.

> **If the SWI-Prolog kernel is statically linked** (default on Linux/i386) and the state does not use external packages that provide shared objects, you are done. **Otherwise, you must make the shared objects available and findable** to make the program usable on another computer.

It looks like your original SWI-Prolog install makes use of shared libraries, which will have to bundled with your executable manually, as mentioned on the page:

> If the SWI-Prolog kernel is statically linked (default on Linux/i386) and the state does not use external packages that provide shared objects, you are done. Otherwise, you must make the shared objects available and findable to make the program usable on another computer.

Comment: hehe... no offense but copy pasting from the link I just sent is not really a good answer. The problem is I don't know how to bundle them manually. Can you provide an example?